# Need bring actual date in .yalm file

Tags: testing, tavern

I'm using "tavern" for testing a Django API rest. I pretty new in this library and I don't know if my question is posible but need the date atribute in second header, bring a current date and not hard-code one.

Is it possible?

```
stages:
  - name: login
    request:
      url: http//......
      json:
        email: email
        password: pass
      method: POST
      headers:
        content-type: application/json
    response:
      status_code: 200
      body:
        {
          "refresh": refresh token
          "access": access token
          "id": 1,
          "username": username,
          "email": email,
          "first_name": name,
          "last_name": last,
          "group": group,
          "manager": null,
          "profile_photo": photo
        } 
      headers:
        content-type: application/json
        Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS
        Content-Type: application/json
        Vary: Accept
        x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN 
        connection: close 
        server: Werkzeug/0.12.2 Python/3.6.2
        date: { here is the field }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The possible solution is write the following line on top

```
strict: False
```

That will allow you which attribute you want evaluate or which not